# Fidelity of measurement using conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Let me begin by saying that I'm not entirely sure if this is the correct forum, or if Mathematics would be more suitable. The problem I'm about to describe is statistical in nature, so I suppose it fits here.

I have a system $m_I$ that is either in state 1, 0 or -1. In order to determine which state it is in, I measure a different (related) system $N$ times, and I count how many 'positive occurances' $k$ I get. The chance of a positive occurrence is $p_i$, so this is binomially distributed. Depending on the state $m_I$, the there is a different $p_i$, so in principle I should measure three binomial distributions. These three binomial distributions have two intersections, $k1$ and $k2$. In order to decide what state of $m_I$ I'm dealing with, I simply see what distribution it was most likely to belong to by seeing on what side of the values $k_1$ and $k_2$ my measurement is.

I want to optimize the fidelity of being correct about $m_I$ which I call $F_{avg} = \frac{1}{3}(F_1+F_0+F_{-1})$, which is defined using the cumulative distribution function of the binomial distribution

$
P(X \leq k) = \textrm{Bincdf}(k,n,p) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \left (\begin{matrix}
    n \\
    i 
\end{matrix}\right )p^i(1-p)^{n-i}
$

and

$
F_{1} = 1 - P(X \leq k_2)
$

$
F_{0} = P(X \leq k_2) - P(X \leq k_1)
$

$
F_{-1} = P(X \leq k_1)
$

The fidelities are thus simply the chance that a certain $k$ belongs to the interval of one of the three binomial distributions. Here the probabilities $p$ are fixed, but $k1,k2$ vary when I vary $n$.

Now, $k_1$ and $k_2$ I can numerically calculate for a specific $N$, and I can thus also just evaluate $F_{avg}$ for various $N$. This shows, as is to be expected, that it converges to 1 very quickly as the distributions become more narrow for higher $N$. But here's where the problem comes in. What I have not included in this model is that every time I make a measurement (so I make $N$ in total), there is a chance $P$ that something goes wrong and that my approach is no longer valid. Basically, by measuring I have a chance of changing $m_I = 1$ into $m_I = 0$, and the other permutations. Now, for simplicity lets say that 1 can only go to 0, 0 to -1 and -1 to 1, all with the same chance P.

My problem is, how do I include this in my fidelities. What I first thought of was just simply multiplying each $F$ by a factor of $(1-P)^N$, which is the chance that the system has not changed in N measurements. But my feeling is that this is not correct, and that the approach is a little more intricate. Intuitively the notion of a convolution comes to mind, but I'm not sure how applicable that is?

I apologize if my story is vague. I've tried rewriting it about 4 times now, and this is as legible as I can currently make it, but that's also because I know the situation very well. So if there's any part that is particularly unclear, please let me know and I'll try to rephrase it!